# Is it possible to place in power bi prophet html forecast?

Tags: html, r, powerbi, facebook-prophet

Does anyone succed to do this to place prophet html in power bi sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [HTML Viewer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381214) custom visual.

> This visualization allows you to display your HTML text string (e.g. rich-text columns from SharePoint) in its original style and formatting with wrapping. Provided content formatting options allow you to easily control and change the overall font size, color and alignment.

When you download it, you will get one `.pbiviz` file. In Power BI Desktop, select the ellipsis at the bottom of Visualizations pane and select `Import from file`. Then browse for the file you just got. For more information about installation of custom visuals, see [Import a custom visual from a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-custom-visuals#import-a-custom-visual-from-a-file).

Comment: As far as i understood what you have said is possible solution when i create html file separetly in r studio for example and then add it as an html file to power bi. but i want power bi immediately show what i got after my code of r in power bi was apllied